# 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

Tags: c#

have no reason why that code acts like showed, any ideas?

```
using DriverLicensePracticerApi.Entities;
using System.Linq;

namespace DriverLicensePracticerApi.Services
{
    public class CategoryService
    {
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _dbContext;

        public CategoryService(ApplicationDbContext dbContext)
        {
            _dbContext = dbContext;
        }

        public void setupCategories(string categoriesToSplit, int questionId)
        {
            
            var question = _dbContext.Questions.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == questionId);
            var splittedCategories = categoriesToSplit.Split(',').ToList();
            foreach (var category in splittedCategories)
            {
                
                switch (category)
                {
                    case "A":
                        var wtf = _dbContext.Categories.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == 1);
                        question.Categories.Add(_dbContext.Categories.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == 1));
                        break;
                    case "B":
                        question.Categories.Add(_dbContext.Categories.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == 2));
                        break;
                    case "C":
                        question.Categories.Add(_dbContext.Categories.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == 3));
                        break;
                    case "D":
                        question.Categories.Add(_dbContext.Categories.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == 4));
                        break;
                    case "T":
                        question.Categories.Add(_dbContext.Categories.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == 5));
                        break;
                    case "AM":
                        question.Categories.Add(_dbContext.Categories.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == 6));
                        break;
                    case "A1":
                        question.Categories.Add(_dbContext.Categories.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == 7));
                        break;
                    case "A2":
                        question.Categories.Add(_dbContext.Categories.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == 8));
                        break;
                    case "B1":
                        question.Categories.Add(_dbContext.Categories.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == 9));
                        break;
                    case "C1":
                        question.Categories.Add(_dbContext.Categories.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == 10));
                        break;
                    case "D1":
                        question.Categories.Add(_dbContext.Categories.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == 11));
                        break;
                    case "PT":
                        question.Categories.Add(_dbContext.Categories.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == 12));
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CdWM7.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sb8yV.png)

Comment: Not really, as showed on screenshots, its not null return query, but in function acts like it is

Comment: Ok, `wtf` is not null, what about `question` ?

Comment: I would guess either `question.Categories` is null (Empty list won't cause it), or the First dbContext.Category returned by dbContext.Categories for .FirstOrDefault is null. You can break it into 2 lines and see what return as null or exception.

Comment: Also no need to query database in loop - map `splittedCategories` to list of ids and use query with `listOfIds.Contains` logic.

Comment: question is not null too, the question.Categories is prop from model, should i initialize it somehow before adding objects to it?

Comment: Looks like a ‘question.Categories’ is null. Add ‘.Include(x=>x.Categories)’ to the line where you query db for ‘question’: ‘ var question = _dbContext.Questions.Include(x=>x.Categories).FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == questionId);’

Comment: Yes, after checking it is. So there is question should i initialize before referring to it?

Comment: Thought it creates with model creation

Comment: Sorry it’s hard to replay on the phone… Add ‘.Include(x=>x.Categories)’ to the line where you query db for ‘question’: ‘var question = _dbContext.Questions.Include(x=>x.Categories).FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == questionId);’

Comment: Include() in EF is translated to ‘join’ in the SQL. EntityFramework doesn’t include sub-entities by default - you need be explicit about that… See more in EF docs.

Comment: ` var toAdd = _dbContext.Categories.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == 1); `
This shows as object of Category, added Include Statement and still question.Categories is null

Comment: In model i declare that list like that '  public List<Category> Categories { get; set; } '
maybe it is wrong way?

Comment: But that’s different. Categories are in the db, but aren’t included/joint to the ‘question’ by default… you need explicitly include categories to question. This is EF feature. More information can be found in the EF docs under include and navigation properties sections.

Comment: Did you try this ‘var question = _dbContext.Questions.Include(x=>x.Categories).FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == questionId);’ ?

Comment: var question = _dbContext.Questions.Include(x => x.Categories).FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == questionId); 

As you mentioned before i did it, and variable 

var questionCategories = question.Categories;

still returns null

Comment: Hmm… I don’t remember how it works if collection under navigation property is empty… I would expect that collection to be initialised  anyway. Unfortunately I have no access to my PC right now so I cannot test that.

Comment: Perhaps relation between question and categories is not correct either in the db or db context.

Comment: Try to search SO or Google why navigation property is null after include.

Comment: And one more - check if ‘question.Categories’ is declared as virtual property in your model? (assuming you are doing code first). That’s required for Include to work.